# Python - Extracting Instances of Text from File

Tags: python, parsing, text, html-parsing

I'm a beginner at python, and I'm working on a project that parses comments from an Instagram post to determine who commented first. I have everything working except for the parsing of the large text file I get when I pull the comments from the Instagram API. I tried using a split statement to split by the instance of "id", but that didn't do what I want, and I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Text file I'm trying to parse is here: https://pastebin.com/SjyaUZ1u

Code is below

```
with open("comments.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        str = line.split("id", 10)
        print(str)
```

Eventually I'd like to output these instances along with following text into another file, but this is the main problem right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- using `BeautifulSoup` and its `html.parser` parse your html
- find the `json` content inside `pre` tag
- convert it into dictionary format
- get the data using keys.

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
content = open('comments.txt')

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

a = soup.find('pre').get_text()

# print(a)

data = json.loads(a)
# print(data['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_media_to_comment']['edges'])
comments = data['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_media_to_comment']['edges']

for i in comments:
    print(i)
```

output:

```
{'node': {'id': '17866050361316207', 'text': '@pay2on gimme that coin', 'created_at': 1549838809, 'did_report_as_spam': False, 'owner': {'id': '351807810', 'is_verified': False, 'profile_pic_url': 'https://scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/3d9c34d98843652774cbe4ed24111890/5CDB0369/t51.2885-19/s150x150/46791596_1837989999663259_8814990427338833920_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com', 'username': 'pay2on'}, 'viewer_has_liked': False, 'edge_liked_by': {'count': 0}}}
{'node': {'id': '18015390769112027', 'text': 'Gg', 'created_at': 1549838810, 'did_report_as_spam': False, 'owner': {'id': '1620477479', 'is_verified': False, 'profile_pic_url': 'https://scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/386991ecd3581167df6fbcdcc3fbffba/5CDA79E7/t51.2885-19/s150x150/43093738_486110321900668_5555852948304560128_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com', 'username': 'a_andrestares'}, 'viewer_has_liked': False, 'edge_liked_by': {'count': 0}}}
{'node': {'id': '18032678767050139', 'text': '', 'created_at': 1549838821, 'did_report_as_spam': False, 'owner': {'id': '10336797539', 'is_verified': False, 'profile_pic_url': 'https://scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/a76a0efe6e172d370cd1e78d91fd0dd8/5CF3F51A/t51.2885-19/50496250_242828456650749_2095120626497880064_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com', 'username': 'sourpods'}, 'viewer_has_liked': False, 'edge_liked_by': {'count': 0}}}
{'node': {'id': '18031342408039828', 'text': '@pay2on anticoin', 'created_at': 1549838844, 'did_report_as_spam': False, 'owner': {'id': '4726002591', 'is_verified': False, 'profile_pic_url': 'https://scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/124d070772b728492cb4a2aa00ff7919/5D01194C/t51.2885-19/s150x150/49303395_379094076216927_6321318684270788608_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com', 'username': 'anti.tv'}, 'viewer_has_liked': False, 'edge_liked_by': {'count': 0}}}
{'node': {'id': '17900497066291896', 'text': 'H9', 'created_at': 1549838912, 'did_report_as_spam': False, 'owner': {'id': '9667789306', 'is_verified': False, 'profile_pic_url': 'https://scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/de6dfba0978218656579b080ee53f8c4/5CE83473/t51.2885-19/s150x150/50746304_2379848008910407_7742041896683307008_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-1.cdninstagram.com', 'username': 'chronic_wanna_be'}, 'viewer_has_liked': False, 'edge_liked_by': {'count': 0}}}
```